# F3 ORM add new record omitting some fields

Tags: postgresql, fat-free-framework

I have a postgres table in which I have some "defaulted" fields like date_created which automatically receives a current_timestamp as default.

or the ID field which gets it's value from a sequence defined in the database.

What would be (if possible) the syntax to tell the ORM module to not include these two fields when generating an INSERT statement ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a function as 2nd parameter to remove the fields:

```
$this->copyfrom('POST',function($val) {
    unset($val['ID']);
    unset($val['date_created']);
    return $val
});
```

or to only copy allowed fields from the POST array:

```
$this->copyfrom('POST',function($val) {
    return array_intersect_key($val, array_flip(array('name','age')));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using an HTML form to add new records into the tables, follow the steps below;

1. In the form, omit these 'defaulted' fields, i.e. add only the fields that you want to submit
2. Create a model with a function similar to below

   ```
   public function add() {
       $this->copyFrom ( 'POST' );
       $this->save ();
   }
   ```
3. Create a route that links the form to this function

Comment: these fields are used for update/delete so can't be removed from the form; But I see where you're coming from and I suppose I could remove those from the POST array in case of an insert.